# Can't access laravel language files in external directory

Tags: php, laravel, localization

I have a Laravel 4.2 application which should support multiple languages. All my language files are placed `inside _application/assets/lang`. Not in `app/lang`. To access a value I use this:

```
Lang::get('namespace::strings.value');
```

This returns `'namespace::strings.value'` and not the actual value, so it doesn't work. In `global.php`, I've added the following to register a namespace

```
Lang::addNamespace('namespace', '_application/assets/lang');
```